How to resolve missing firmware warnings in on Arch Linux?
Hey i am a new arch user and i am getting these i try to update my firmware but none is solved i know they are harmless but they slowdown pc
I'm encountering the following warnings while running sudo mkinitcpio -P on my Arch Linux system:
Possibly missing firmware for module: 'xhci_pci'

Possibly missing firmware for module: 'ast'

Possibly missing firmware for module: 'bfa'


Possibly missing firmware for module: 'qed'

Possibly missing firmware for module: 'qla1280'


Possibly missing firmware for module: 'aic94xx'

Possibly missing firmware for module: 'wd719x'

Possibly missing firmware for module: 'qla2xxx'

Possibly missing firmware for module: 'xhci_pci_renesas'

How can I determine if these firmware files are necessary for my system and resolve these warnings?
Should I ignore them if I don't experience hardware issues?

Arch mkinitcpio -P can make multiple initramfs images according to the number of preset files you have in /etc/mkinitcpio.d/. By default, each preset may define two images: a default image optimized specifically for your system, and a fallback image that includes all the available kernel modules, to allow you to boot the system even if you replace the motherboard with a different model or otherwise make major changes to your hardware.
Generating the fallback image is likely to generate most of the spurious "missing firmware" warnings, as it will include all the modules available in the kernel configuration, not just what your system actually needs right now.
To get more information of each module with missing firmware, first run:
sudo modinfo <module name> | grep -e ^filename -e ^description -e ^alias -e ^firmware

For example:
$ sudo modinfo ast |grep -e ^filename -e ^description -e ^alias -e ^firmware

filename:       /lib/modules/<kernel version>/kernel/drivers/gpu/drm/ast/ast.ko
description:    AST
firmware:       ast_dp501_fw.bin
alias:          pci:v00001A03d00002010sv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001A03d00002000sv*sd*bc03sc*i*

For this module the description is so brief it does not tell anything useful, but the path in the filename field indicates this is some sort of GPU driver. If your system does not include a GPU made by AST or you do have one but it already works to your satisfaction, you obviously don't need the firmware.
The firmware line simply identifies the firmware file this module might need. If a module supports a lot of devices, the firmware file might be only needed for some of them.
If all else fails, from the alias lines you can find the vendor and device IDs this module is autoloaded for: in this case, PCI(e) devices with Vendor ID 1A03 and device IDs 2010 or 2000. You can look them up in the PCI ID Repository for PCI(e) devices, or in the USB ID Repository for USB devices respectively.
In this example looking up the PCI vendor ID brings up this list of device IDs. Device ID 2000 is an exact match for ASPEED Graphics Family, i.e. a family of server-oriented GPU+BMC+KVM chips. Device ID 2010 is unlisted, but is probably a newer version of a similar product.
See also: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Mkinitcpio#Possibly_missing_firmware_for_module_XXXX
Most of the modules you've listed are mentioned in the table on that ArchWiki page, along with information on where to get the firmware. There's also information on disabling the fallback image generation.
